# How to filter data table column using custom filer

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

HI i want to filter my data table using the select option and following is my code.

**Table**

[image]

```
var t = $('#warehouseList').DataTable( {
        'columnDefs': [
              {
                "targets": 0,
                "orderable": false
              }
           ],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "<?=site_url('purchase_order/master/inwardData')?>",
        error: function(){  // error handling
          $(".warehouseList-error").html("");
          $("#warehouseList").append('<tbody class="warehouseList-error"><tr><th colspan="7">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
          $("#warehouseList_processing").css("display","none");
        }
    });

    $('#POStat').change(function(){
         t
        .columns(8)
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
    });
```

whenever i change the option, It just refresh the table, but not filtering according to the value selected. Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Tried this [link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) ?

Comment: columns are zero-indexed. Therefore your 9th column will be index 8, not index 9.

Comment: @ADyson i first tried with 8 but not worked, so changed to 9. Updating it to 8 right.

Comment: Thanks @brijeshchowdarylavu will try this and back to you.

Comment: @brijeshchowdarylavu i want the filter for server side and the drop down to select the options or i can submit the form to filter the table.

Comment: Also please make sure that your server-side script supports column searching.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com can you please share server side script.

Comment: See [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) and "Server-side script" tab that shows usage of `ssp.class.php` helper library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i solved this problem with  using the PHP session. When i select the option from drop down using ajax request saved the search key in session variable. and destroy the current table initialization using `t.destroy();`.

In and then reinitialized the data table from php function/script where i can get the filtered result.

I don't know it is correct approach or not but it helped me to filter result. May be it helps anyone.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="postatus" style="float: left;">
                <!--form id="managePOstatus" action="<?=site_url('purchase_order/master/inwardData2')?>" method="POST" id="filterPO"-->
                    <select id="POStat" name="orderstatus" class="input-text">
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Option</option>
                        <option value="pickup_confirm">Pickup Confirmed</option>
                        <option value="pickup_assign">Pickup Person Assign</option>
                        <option value="product_delivered">Product Delivered</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="button" value="Filter" id="filterPO">
                    <input type="button" value="Reset" id="filterPOReset" disabled>
                <!--/form-->
                </div>    
<table id="warehouseList" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th width="5%"><input type="checkbox" id="selector"></th>
                                  <th width="10%">PO ID</th>
                                  <th width="15%">Product Name</th>
                                  <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
                                  <th width="10%">warehouse ID</th>
                                  <th width="10%">Seller Name</th>
                                  <th width="10%">Price</th>
                                  <th width="10%">Total Price</th>
                                  <th width="10%">Status</th>
                                  <th width="10%">Date</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>

                        </table>
```

JS Code:

```
var t = $('#warehouseList').DataTable( {
        // 'searching': false,
        'columnDefs': [
              {
                "targets": 0,
                "orderable": false
              }
           ],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "<?=site_url('purchase_order/master/inwardData')?>",
        error: function(){  // error handling
          $(".warehouseList-error").html("");
          $("#warehouseList").append('<tbody class="warehouseList-error"><tr><th colspan="7">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
          $("#warehouseList_processing").css("display","none");
        }
    });
$('#filterPO').click(function(){
        t.destroy();
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        $('#filterPOReset').prop('disabled', false);
        var stat = $('#POStat').val();
        var req = 'yes';
        console.log('value sent:'+stat);
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
              type : 'POST',
              data:{status:stat,req:req},
              url: "<?=site_url('purchase_order/master/inwardData3')?>", // call here the function to get  

              success: function (data)
              {
                  console.log(data);
              }

        });

        $('#warehouseList').DataTable({
        'columnDefs': [
              {
                "targets": 0,
                "orderable": false
              }
           ],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "<?=site_url('purchase_order/master/inwardData2')?>",       
        error: function(){  
          $(".warehouseList-error").html("");
          $("#warehouseList").append('<tbody class="warehouseList-error"><tr><th colspan="7">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
          $("#warehouseList_processing").css("display","none");
        }
    });
    });
```

function inwardData contains the default table, inwardData3 saves the search value in session and inwardData2 loads the filtered data. But i need to reset the page using `location.reload()` after each filter.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
.search( this.value )
```

should be

```
.search($("#POStat :selected").val())
```

Or depending on your select option.

Comment: It's not the case because it gives me the search value in headers like `columns[8][search][value]:pickup_assign` @Henz